# Wired connection doesn't work , but wireless does

Tags: networking, router, internet, ethernet, adsl-router

WiFi works fine. Ethernet connection is where I am having a problem.

I tried changing cables I tried 4 different ones all new.

Thought maybe my network cards are faulty so I tried 3 different laptops that have the right drivers same problem.

I tried google's static dns both on pc , and router no dice .

I can't get my head around it.

router : d-link DSL-2750U
Firmware : Me_1.03
OS : windows

Comment: Have you checked that the Wired connection is not disabled?

Comment: What doesn't work? You haven't given us enough information to start from. Do you get connection lights right through - yellow or green? Can it find a DHCP server or does it get a private address?

Comment: @Tetsujin , yes , i get connection lights right thru green (and wifi works) . though in order to get the wired connection working on my pc i have to restart the router , once it gets restarted the Ethernet works fine for 2 minutes then stops (wifi works) . yes it can find a DHCP server.
Thanks for you response .

Comment: @Carles How do i do that ? , is there a setting in the router configuration ?

Comment: If your connection works fine for a while then this is not the issue. I would recommend you to first check for trojans and malware using something like Spybot or Malwarebytes, which provide of free versions; then scan for viruses using any anti-virus. Once you are sure that the computer is clean, then if the issue persists, you should try to upgrade the network drivers. If this does not still fix the issue I would try to run a live CD of Ubuntu, for example. If the network also fails there, then this is a hardware problem and you should get a USB network adapter.

Comment: @Carles Thank you for your help , i tried all of the above and no results . I believe it's a router issue but i can't narrow it down to exactly what it is .

Comment: You can find out whether it is a router issue or not by connecting to the network from a different location/router

Comment: It seems that there is an upgraded firmware for that router. You can try to upgrade or even downgrade the firmware: https://dlinkmea.com/index.php/product/details?det=c0lvN0JoeVVhSXh4TVhjTnd1OUpUUT09

Comment: @Carles Thank you , I'll try updating the firmware and keep you updated with the results.